# Failed to compile SASS

Tags: css, url, sass

When using SASS, a compilation error occurs when using a url in the code

> ERROR in ./src/app/content/content.component.sass Module Error (from
>   ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js): (Emitted value instead of
>   an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
>   D:\Angular\ng-proj\src\app\content\content.component.sass:34:19: Can't
>   resolve '%22%22' in 'D:\Angular\ng-proj\src\app\content'

```
 .content:hover
        .details-img
            content: url('../assets/img/content-selected.jpg')
        .title
            color: #e7ba2f
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to get the ".." for the URL.
Thanks!

Comment: I think it's probably better just to delete your question. I don't see how this answer helps others with the same problem.